# What does the "one" in lightning url structure reference?

Tags: lightning, url, salesforce1-platform

The URL pattern of lightning is https://instance.lightning.force.com/one/one.app.

**one.app** is a lightning app.

My question is about the **one** after the domain name: What does the *one* relate to in lightning url structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"one/one.app" is a reference to Salesforce1. The same URL is used both for loading Salesforce1 and Lightning. If you're on a mobile device (phone or tablet), you'll see Salesforce1, while if you're on a desktop, you'll see Salesforce Lightning. Salesforce1 has a reduced memory footprint for mobile devices, and also has a separate app you can use to provide additional security (e.g. an app PIN to prevent unauthorized access). They are both fundamentally the same technology, but Salesforce1 was the original Lightning before Lightning was a real term.

Answer (score 2):

Lightning pages are served up from a different server than visualforce pages. The one/one is also a reference to the way Salesforce1 Apps have always been referenced. This is what the Lightning Platform has been built upon which has now been extended to the desktop. More than anything, it's important to remember that Lightning pages are single page apps and individual parts of the page can't be easily referenced directly if multiple objects/pages are contained within the app.